# Spring MVC CIRCULAR VIEW PATH

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using the spring mvc and the view is throwing the 500 error .
getting the error on the console

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [index]: would
>   dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your
>   ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified
>   view, due to default view name generation.)   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:315)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]

the github link for this project is

https://github.com/dishankgoyal/project

mv

Answer (score 1):

Add this `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >`
to your html tag. 
and add this dependency to your pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

comments are welcome :)

Comment: I want to ise the javascript with spring mvc.

Comment: @dishank put your js files under the **static** folder
and show the path of js file like this 
`<script th:src="@{waves.js}"></script>`